# call web service through ssrs using a wsdl as the endpoint

Tags: web-services, soap, reporting-services

I have to create a report using SSRS in VS. I must call a SOAP WebService using a wsdl endpoint, and taken in and passing parameters to the service. Has anyone ever done this before?
The error that I am getting is that it does not like the way I am passing in the parameter
Error message: tried to invoke a method, throws java.rmi.RemoteException,com.fds.www.schemas.fault.BusinessFault,com.fds.www.schemas.fault.System'
with argumrents classes 'java.util.ArrayList' against object

Answer (score 2):

EDIT FOR REWRITE AS WEBSERVICE AS A DATASET:

Generally when choosing a webservice as a dataset I do a few things:

1. Set up a datasource as 'XML' as the type.
2. Put in your address of service.  EG: http:// localhost/Reporting/ReportingService.svc
   My service is for an HTTP binding hosted locally of a WCF service.
3. SSRS has this weird way of querying soap that I am still not completely used to.  I know this method works for me but these assume the default namespaces of WCF and yours may be different.

   ```
   < Query>  
   < Method Name="GetMonthlyData2" Namespace="http://tempuri.org/">  
   < Parameters>  
   < Parameter Name="aStart" Type="Date">< /Parameter>  
   < Parameter Name="aEnd" Type="Date">< /Parameter>  
   < /Parameters>  
   < /Method>
   <  SoapAction>  
     http://tempuri.org/IReportingService/GetMonthlyData2  
   <  /SoapAction>
   </Query>
   ```

More info on query method here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345251.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but I am not using java to the SSRS. SSRS is the BI tool that I am using to graphical display the data pulled back from the xml query, which is also calling a web service method(in order to get the data). I hop this makes sense.

Comment: So are you using the Webservice for the populating the 'Dataset' in an existing report in SSRS?  Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Yes the webservice is the source of the data.

Comment: See updated as an example, I did this with hooking to a WCF service before.

Comment: Thank, I have one more question, my connection string has a "wsdl" extention, which is also the endpoint location of the web service call. Should that connection string have a .svc extention??

Comment: I'm kind of a novice on services to be honest.  I use them when I need to but don't much beyond basic endpoints, hosting, and binding.  I always thought a wsdl was just the interpretation of the service by the hosting service giving an explanation to a user/developer.  Most commonly services are discovered with an .svc and the host controller may offer a wsdl to you.

Comment: OK, thanks for the inforamtion you have been very help. I too am a novice on web services. I did not create this I am just being ask to call it. However thanks for all of the information that you have provided!!!!!!!